# Checkbox selection order issue with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I've got a base background image and two checkboxes. I need replace the background image (via toggle class) with the correct class depending on which checkbox is selected. If both checkboxes are selected I need it to show the black background.

http://jsfiddle.net/2k96D/6/

```
$('#ax_lab').change(function () {
    if ($('#ax_ov').is(':checked')) {
        $('.axial').toggleClass('axial_all');
    } else{
        $('.axial').toggleClass('axial_lab');
    }
});

$('#ax_ov').change(function () {
    if ($('#ax_lab').is(':checked')) {
        $('.axial').toggleClass('axial_all');
    } else{
        $('.axial').toggleClass('axial_over');
    }
});
```

My fiddle works perfectly when I select and deselect in the same order, however, if I de-select the checkboxes in a different order than the order I selected them in, it doesn't default back to the original class. I know there must be a flaw in my logic, I'm just having trouble finding it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more explicit with the logic. Here's what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateAxialStatus() {
        var axOv = $('#ax_ov').prop('checked'),
            axLab = $('#ax_lab').prop('checked');

        $('.axial').removeClass('axial_all axial_lab axial_over');
        if (axOv && axLab)
            $('.axial').addClass('axial_all');
        else if (axOv)
            $('.axial').addClass('axial_over');
        else if (axLab)
            $('.axial').addClass('axial_lab');
    }

    $('#ax_lab, #ax_ov').change(updateAxialStatus);
});
```

That version just explicitly checks the status of the two checkboxes and updates the class to reflect the status. The same handler can be used for both checkboxes.

Note that old versions of IE may not fire the "change" event for checkboxes until the checkbox loses focus, but you can safely use "click" instead.

Comment: Fairly new yet to JS so the thought of creating variables to represent it's checked status hadn't even occurred to me. One question, what function does this line serve. "...change(updateAxialStatus);"

Comment: @user1504591 that sets up the event handler for both of the checkboxes. The "id" selectors are combined with a comma. The name of the update function is passed in, so it'll be used as the event handler.

Comment: so both the id's are in the line with the event handler, and the function as well. So clicking either id calls "change" for the function of updateAxialStatus, which then adds or removes the class based on the conditions in the if statement? Sorry for the run-on.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.  Removing and re-adding the classes is cheap, so this might seem a little inelegant, but it's simple and it works :)